# sqlite GROUP BY missing a row

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I have a table of records with unique IDs cross joined to itself on a ControlID which matches similar records.

Initial table:

```
ID (key), ControlID (records match), ... other fields
31 | 56 ...
32 | 56 ...
33 | 56 ...
```

Joined table:

```
ID, ControlID, ID (2), ControlID (2), ..., matchID (sum of ID keys)
31 | 56 | 32 | 56 ... 63
31 | 56 | 33 | 56 ... 64
32 | 56 | 31 | 56 ... 63
32 | 56 | 33 | 56 ... 65
33 | 56 | 31 | 56 ... 64
33 | 56 | 32 | 56 ... 65
```

I need to eliminate the rows which duplicate ID combinations, hence the matchID. I only need one row for each matchID and ControlID combination.
So I figured `GROUP BY ControlID, matchID` would work. Here's my result:

```
33 | 56 | 31 | 56 ... 64
33 | 56 | 32 | 56 ... 65
```

Why does this not include the following row?

```
31 | 56 | 32 | 56 ... 63
```

Or this row?

```
32 | 56 | 31 | 56 ... 63
```

One of the rows with a matchID of 63 should be returned, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

I just added a condition that `ID < ID (2)`. That gives the necessary result, but I still don't understand why the `GROUP BY` doesn't work.